# Hive AVRO table creation syntax

Tags: hive, avro

What are the differences between these two syntaxes in Hive to create an Avro table?

```
CREATE TABLE db.mytable (fields...)
STORED AS AVRO
...
```

```
CREATE TABLE db.mytable (fields...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
...
```

Comment: No difference, except one is verbose

Comment: Thanks, the 'describe formatted table' command returns the same things in both cases indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, one is verbose, that's all. How to check? You can run the command

```
describe formatted db.yourtable;
```

you will see that the Serde used by Hive (for the non verbose table created) is the same that the one in the verbose version.